# UIPageControl with multiple viewable pages on iPad

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to make an application that uses a UIScrollview and UIPageControl. Ideally, I'd like to build something that has a similar look to the E*Trade app running on the iPad.

The E*Trade app allows for what looks like a page control in a scrollview, but the pages in the scroll view are smaller than the width of the scrollview, so multiple pages show at one time. When the user swipes, the existing pages move, and a new page is added to the scroller.

From looking at the docs, it seems like the UIPageControl in iOS can only show a single page. Does anyone have any pointers to docs, examples, tutorials, etc that can point me in the right direction for creating something that can display multiple pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIPageControl is simply a means of providing a paging widget - the paging itself is handled within the UIScrollView. (Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "the UIPageControl in iOS can only show a single page".)

Irrespective, using a UIScrollView alongside a UIPageControl is quite a common UI idiom - Apple's own [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code uses this exact approach, so this would be a good first port of call.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the UIScrollview shows multiple pages, and the UIPageControl highlights multiple boxes to show which of the pages are being displayed.